# What is the difference between queryIntentActivities() and resolveActivity().Which one is the best approach to know about existing apps for a intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-implicit-intent

As I can see in Android documentation when trying to build implicit intents when sending the user to another app. These are the two approaches to avoid ActivityNotFoundException.

First one :

```
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, location);

PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
    PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;
```

Second one :

```
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, title);
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {

}
```

Now my doubt is whats the differnece and which one should i use ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Depends what you want to do.

If you just want to prevent 'ActivityNotFoundException', either method will work. Neither is "best". They do basically the same thing. You want to know if there is at least 1 `Activity` that can handle your `Intent`.

Otherwise:

- `queryIntentActivities()` returns a list of all activities that can handle the `Intent`.
- `resolveActivity()` returns the "best" `Activity` that can handle the `Intent`

Therefore, if you want to know all the activities that can handle your `Intent`, you would use `queryIntentActivities()` and if you want to know what Android thinks is the "best" `Activity`, then you would use `resolveActivity()`.

Answer (score 5):

From Docs

- [**`queryIntentActivities`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities(android.content.Intent,%20int))

Retrieve all activities that can be performed for the given intent.

- [**`resolveActivity`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#resolveActivity(android.content.Intent,%20int))

Determine the best action to perform for a given Intent.
 This is how `Intent.resolveActivity(PackageManager)` finds an activity if a class has not been explicitly specified.

**Note:** if using an implicit Intent (without an explicit ComponentName specified), be sure to consider whether to set the `MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY` only flag. You need to do so to resolve the activity in the same way that `Context.startActivity(Intent)` and `Intent.resolveActivity(PackageManager)` do.

Comment: which one should we use when we create implicit intent?

Comment: still doesn't explain which one is best to create implicit intent

Answer (score 2):

In short, `queryIntentActivities` returns a `List` of all available `ResolveInfo` that can handle your given `Intent` and in contrast `resolveActivity` returns the single best suited `ResolveInfo`.

Hence, one can be used to show a **chooser** and the other can be used to launch the app directly.

For more info, read their official documents.

Comment: if this can we used to show a chooser then what does Intent.createChooser(intent, title); do ?

Comment: @AjayChauhan When you directly use `createChooser()` you can control some of the behaviour (ie: setting the "title" for the chooser).  When Android creates the chooser itself (because it needs the user to pick something to complete `resolveActivity()`), it uses the default chooser.